# How to develop multilanguage app

Tags: c#, windows-phone, multilingual

I'm developing an app that supports two languages, user can change the language tapping a textblock in top/right of the screen, the language is saved into a global variable.

what's the best way to load that text for the correct language?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found these links useful in the past when I used to develop for windows phone

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965328.aspx

and this

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/01/18/start-building-an-international-application-for-wp-7-part-i.aspx

Hope it helps!